# ASP.NET Trouble Routing to View On Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to .NET and C#, having trouble routing to my one view file on app start. There must be something I don't understand about the routing, because the URL in the browser:

```
/Views/LoadCustomerAndDisplay/Index.cshtml
```

seems right to me. However, I get a 404 error when I build and run the app. Here is a picture of the file structure:

[image]

and here is the browser error:

[image]

**`RouteConfig`:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**`LoadCustomerAndDisplayController`:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class LoadCustomerAndDisplayController : Controller 
    {
        // GET: LoadCustomerAndDisplay
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
            objCustomer.Id = 1001;
            objCustomer.CustomerCode = "C";
            objCustomer.Amount = 900.78;
            return View(objCustomer);
        }
    }
}
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: You should not access the cshtml directly. Access it via an action method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660232/created-a-new-view-in-mvc-5-opening-the-new-view-results-in-http-404

Comment: ok gotcha, aren't I doing that with Index()?

Comment: The url you should try to access is  `LoadCustomerAndDisplay/Index`

Comment: o sorry i understand what your saying, I can't call the file as .cshtml

Comment: Yea. Read the other link i posted above.

Comment: Route config looks ok

Comment: Can you paste your controller code? I've updated my answer with an aproximation of how it should look

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the `.cshtml` via the browser. The correct URL would be `/LoadCustomerAndDisplay/Index`. It uses the `Index` action of the  `LoadCustomerAndDisplay` controller.

As a side note, you probably want to create a more generic controller name like `Customers` and create any actions relating to your customer entities under that controller.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, [Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) maps virtual "pages" to physical files, and the default route is `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

> The default route table contains a single route (named Default). The
>   Default route maps the first segment of a URL to a controller name,
>   the second segment of a URL to a controller action, and the third
>   segment to a parameter named id.

So in your case, you are calling `/views/LoadCustomerAndDislpay/index.cshtml` but with MVC you don't reference physical files, but instead call `{controller}/{action}`.

Call:

```
/LoadCustomerAndDisplay
```

and it should work. (The `Index` action is the default and can be omitted).

---

This assumes you haven't made any changes to your `RouteConfig`, it should be something like:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

---

I am assuming that your `LoadCustomerAndDisplay` controller looks something like:

```
public class LoadCustomerAndDisplayController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My convention, the controller should be nammed `xxxController` and looking at your file name, that may not be the case.

From [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-controller-cs):

> Notice that the first part of the controller name is highlighted in
>   the Add Controller dialog. Every controller name must end with the
>   suffix Controller. For example, you can create a controller named
>   ProductController but not a controller named Product.

<sub>(admittedly from an older version but its the best version of the quote I could find)</sub>

---

Finally, the View should be in a folder, called the same as the controller, without the controller suffix, so in your case `LoadCustomerAndDisplay`.

Comment: strange, when i call /LoadCustomerAndDisplay I get the same error

Comment: how about explicitly - `/LoadCustomerAndDisplay/Index` ?

Comment: will do, just testing something out real quick

Comment: I've added the default routeconfig, if you (or another dev) hasn't touched it, it should look something like that.

Comment: oooo is it because im not specifying the controller?

Comment: Try renaming it, if it still doesn't fly, post the controller code and I'll take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103539/discussion-between-nikolaidante-and-adam-weitzman).

Comment: Hi @AdamWeitzman I've updated the answer to cover off all the steps we went through and I'd appreciate it if you would consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this one, or let me know of any other detail I need to drop in there. :-)