# Problem while adding new Views in ASP MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 for web development. I have added many Views and they are working. But if I try to add a new View, it cannot be navigated by browser i.e. 404 error occurred. But the rest of the Views are working correctly.

I tried to add new Views in distinct controllers but they have the same problem.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have a controller and action for that view?

Comment: yes, i have controler and action for that view

Comment: i had added about 5 controlers with actions and their views they are working correctly. but new ones not working correctly

Comment: you may share some piece of code. controller and view codes.

Comment: Did you check routes map ?

Comment: How are you adding your Views? Are you creating a View using the default V.S template or are you manually adding them in your Controller and then in your Views folder?

Comment: sorry i cannot add images due to slow internet speed, at the movement

Comment: no i had no cheaked the routes map

Comment: try to copy and paste already existing view and rename it , create controller method and try it.

Comment: i am using EF templates to add views.

Answer (score 0):

[Created a new view in MVC 5, opening the new view results in HTTP 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660232/created-a-new-view-in-mvc-5-opening-the-new-view-results-in-http-404)

> You should be accessing the view through an action method. So If you
>   created your new view in ~/Views/Home/AboutMe.cshtml, You should add
>   an action method like this in your HomeController.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult AboutMe()
   {
     return View();
   }
}
```

> Now you can access this like
>   http://yourServerName/yourAppName/Home/AboutMe
>
> If you want to have your action method in a different controller, You
>   can specify the full view path. Ex : IF you want to add the action
>   method to your Account controller,

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult AboutMe()
   {
      return View("~/Views/Home/aboutme.cshtml");
   }
}
```